# What does the homomorphism from $U(10) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_4$ mapping look like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Given a homomorphism function $f : U(10) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_4$ where $f([3]_{10}) = [3]_4$, find $f([1]_{10}), f([7]_{10})$, and $f([9])_{10}$.

I found that $U(10)$ can be generated by $[3]_{10}$. Then by homomorphism properties
$f(a^n) = f(a)^n$.

So, I this is what I tried to get the $f([1]_{10})$:

> $f([1]_{10}) = f(([3]_{10})^4) = f([3]_{10})^4 = ([3]_4)^4$

However, I'm not sure how to continue it as it is element in $\mathbb{Z}_4$ which the binary operation is addition, or is it just like the usual $3^4$ mod 4?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard calculation that I think you would benefit from doing yourself; having said that, you have made an elementary mistake in what is otherwise the right idea. I will, thus, try to correct it here.

---

Let $(G, \circ), (H, \ast)$ be groups with sets $G,H$ and binary operations $\circ, \ast$, respectively.

We call a map $\varphi: G\to H$ a *homomorphism* if  for all $a,b\in G$,

$$\boxed{\varphi(a\circ b)=\varphi(a)\ast\varphi(b).}$$

That is, homomorphisms *respect operations*.

---

So $$f([3]_{10}^4)=4f([3]_{10}).$$